# Windows XP Service Pack 3 installation on a PC with no Internet connection

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I need to install Windows XP Service Pack 3 on a machine that currently has Windows Xp Service Pack 2.

What is the right way to do it?

Someone suggested downloading the executable from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24) and installing it.

Will this be sufficient to get that machine from Service Pack 2 to Service Pack 3? Or, is there more to be done?

I need Service Pack 3 to install a new Antivirus Software on that machine.

Comment: We're only a few days away from XP end of life. Best solution here is to replace this system with running windows 7 or later.

Comment: It's an old Acer Machine that's unlikely to handle anything more than Windows Xp. Besides, I only need to install an antivirus, so I can get rid of all the viruses in it.

Comment: Antivirus software is **worthless** if you have an unpatched machine. In just a few days, there will be no more new patches issued for XP. This means you're pretty much wasting your time trying to keep virus off this computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats all you need.  You can put it on a USB stick or burn in to a CD.  There are some patches and hotfixes that came after SP3, if I remember correctly.  However, that wouldnt stop you from installing your AV software.

Comment: There are a _lot_ of patches and hotfixes out since SP3.

Comment: One more small question. Should I download the ISO or the exe? What's the difference between those two.

Comment: It doesnt matter as they are identical.  Just different method of distribution.